# MVC variables in model or controller?

Tags: variables, design-patterns, model-view-controller, model, controller

I am trying to understand the MVC Pattern, and I finally understand a lot of it.  There is one concept that I don't quite understand yet.  I have looked through all the posts on here that try to explain MVC, but this one question isn't answered clearly yet.

Do you create variables in the model or the controller or both?

I can see someone passing variables from the controller to the model to change the data held within the variables, but would it be better to create them in the model then just call their values from the controller?  Or would it be better to create variables in the model, and copy their values to the same variables in the controller?

If you know, please explain why one is better than the other, please.  I am asking to understand, not just to know the right answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Persistent data needed throughout the lifetime of the application should be held within the Model.  Model method calls to set, get and manipulate the data within the Model should be done by the Controller.

Temporary data needed by the application or the view (for any reason) ***can*** be held in the controller... but no persistent data should ever be held within the controller, as it's considered to be a bad MVC design pattern implementation to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If I give a straight forward answer for

> Do you create variables in the model or the controller or both?

It doesn't really matter.

The main idea behind ***Model*** and ***Controller*** is

- **Controller** resides only ***Presentation Logic***.
- **Model** resides only ***Business Logic***.
- So that, if you want to present your model with a different presentation logic, you can get your existing **Model** out and plug it with a new **Controller** without any problem because your business logic & presentation logic is decoupled(not mixed with each other).

This is the best diagram I found for MVC architecture. Hope you can upgrade your understanding with this.

[image]

So in terms of variables, in **Model** you should make variables only for business logic purpose. In **Controller**, it's only for presentation purpose. :))

Comment: This is a good diagram, but you can see where my confusion lies.  Even with this beautiful diagram, variables aren't even mentioned.

Comment: @user2470057 there's exactly no problem at all to use variables inside controllers as far as they are not mixed with the business logic of the app. Actually Model is a service provider for the Controller. :))

Comment: @user2470057 if I improve your statement, I would say "The controller takes care of PRESENTATION logic, holds variables, calls model to update the variables that exist in the controller and calls the view to update ACCORDING TO THE UPDATED variables that exist in the controller." :))

Comment: Thank you, that looks like something I can understand now.  I'll wait for a couple of days to make sure everyone agrees with this.
I also found the link you got that image from, and want to make sure the original author gets the credit:
http://www.essenceandartifact.com/2012/12/the-essence-of-mvc.html

Comment: According to the author of that link, he's saying that data is held in the Model though, so from what I'm seeing, variables are not really held in the controller.